# Extjs getCmp loose the reference in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs

I have a ExtJs Window and when I click a button try to print in th browser's console the values of some textfield by the id, it works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome ... I'm really confused.

I'm trying to get the values of `cmb_start_time` and `cmb_end_time`, in Firefox works but not in Chrome

```
Ext.define('form', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

    requires: [
        'Ext.form.Panel'
    ],

    id:'ticket-form',
    height: 608,
    width: 502,
    closeAction: 'close',
    title: 'Edit Ticket',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        archivopdf = "/pdf/pdf_init.pdf";
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'form',
                    height: 608,
                    width: 498,
                    layout: 'absolute',
                    bodyPadding: 10,
                    title: '',
                    items: [

                        {
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            id: 'cmb_start_time',
                            x: 20,
                            y: 180,
                            width: 180,
                            fieldLabel: 'Hora Inicio',
                            store: store_horas,
                            valueField: 'hora24',
                            displayField:'hora12'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            id: 'cmb_end_time',
                            x: 20,
                            y: 210,
                            width: 180,
                            fieldLabel: 'Hora Fin',
                            store: store_horas,
                            valueField: 'hora24',
                            displayField:'hora12'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            x: 310,
                            y: 530,
                            text: 'Limpiar',
                            listeners: {
                                click: function(){
                                    console.log(Ext.getCmp('cmb_start_time').getValue()) //returns NULL
                                    console.log(Ext.getCmp('cmb_end_time').getValue())   //returns NULL
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});

var new_window = Ext.create('form')
```

I realley need to make this work in CHROME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4lu) from your example and it worked for me in Chrome (returning NULL if no value is selected).

But I can't recommend referencing components by their id anyway, so I changed your code to reference the components directly, through code:

In initComponent we create the component, saving a reference in `var` or in `this`, depending on where we need it:

```
initComponent: function() {                
    // ...

    var firstComboBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        id: 'cmb_start_time',
        x: 20,
        y: 180,
        width: 180,
```

we add the reference to the items:

```
this.items = [
    {
        xtype: 'form',
        height: 608,
        width: 498,
        layout: 'absolute',
        bodyPadding: 10,
        title: '',
        items: [
            firstComboBox,
```

and on clicking of the button, we can use the reference:

```
listeners: {
    click: function(){
        console.log(firstComboBox.getValue());
        console.log(secondComboBox.getValue());
    }
}
```